# Xcode Storyboard not updating custom class Designables

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have had many problems after closing `Xcode` which one of them is that Xcode Storyboard is not updating Custom Class Designables anymore and do not show the content. For example I use "SkyFloatingLabelTextField" which worked perfeclty before so I can't blame the library. Is there some way so I can force it to update it?

What I mean illustration:

[image]

As you can see, in the first picture I have assigned the custom class and there is actually `textField` inside my viewController which for some reason doesn't show up anymore in Storyboard but works on real device or simulator.

So can I force it somehow?

I tried removing the class and all runtime values, clean, build close Xcode but nothing is working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Huhh... Enabling "Automatically refresh views" did the trick. For some reason it was turned off in my case. If you do not know what I mean, then it is the setting in **Editor -> Automatically refresh views**

[image]